uLkJSON unit version 1.09 that provides TlkJSON for Delphi 2007 incurs JSON ParseText EDateTimeException with message 'Invalid date string
I have found third party uLkJSON unit, version 1.09, that provides TlkJSON for parsing JSON in Delphi 2007, gives an error for cases where a JSON that contains other JSON as element value(s).
I got around this by passing the JSON back to an adapter DLL written in C# and using Newtonsoft JSON framework for .NET to process the JSON response instead.
Error from TlkJSON.ParseText:
---------------------------
Debugger Exception Notification
---------------------------
Project Project1.exe raised exception class EDateTimeException with > message 'Invalid date string: {\"content\":[{\"report\":{\"status\":\"MEDICARE_REJECT'.
---------------------------
Break   Continue   Help
---------------------------

class procedure TlkJsonDateTime.DTFmtError(AErrorCode: DTErrorCode; const AValue: string);
const
  Errors: array[DTErrorCode] of string = (SInvalidDateString, SInvalidTimeString, SInvalidOffsetString);
begin
  raise EDateTimeException.CreateFmt(Errors[AErrorCode], [AValue]);
end;

This error is "silent" in the app, but the TlkJSONbase item isn't loaded / available after the silent error.
Has anyone else encountered this? Any other solutions?
I find that the earlier version 1.07 of uLkJSON does not have this issue.
Perhaps I will just avoid using the 1.09 version of this.
Example JSON (no real data here)
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "AckDate": "2024-07-25T12:35:30.17",
            "Name": "Report",
            "Request": "{\"claim\":{\"patient\":{\"medicare\":{\"memberNumber\":\"2111111111\",\"memberRefNumber\":\"1\"},\"healthFund\":{\"memberNumber\":\"222222\",\"memberRefNumber\":\"1\",\"organisation\":\"HAM\"},\"identity\":{\"dateOfBirth\":\"1997-09-22\",\"familyName\":\"FLINTSTONE\",\"givenName\":\"FRED\",\"sex\":\"2\"}},\"medicalEvent\":[{\"service\":[{\"dateOfService\":\"2024-06-02\",\"id\":\"0001\",\"chargeAmount\":\"15232\",\"itemNumber\":\"00058\",\"numberOfPatientsSeen\":\"1\"}],\"serviceProvider\":{\"providerNumber\":\"2441301F\"},\"id\":\"01\",\"ifcIssueCode\":\"X\"}],\"principalProvider\":{\"providerNumber\":\"2441301F\"},\"accident\":{\"accidentInd\":\"N\"},\"accountPaidInd\":\"N\",\"accountReferenceId\":\"kj32\",\"claimTypeCode\":\"AG\",\"compensationClaimInd\":\"N\",\"facilityId\":\"0031620B\",\"serviceTypeCode\":\"O\"}}",
            "RequestContentType": "application/json",
            "Response": "{\"content\":[{\"report\":{\"status\":\"MEDICARE_REJECTED\",\"claimSummary\":{\"accountReferenceId\":\"kj32\"},\"medicareStatus\":{\"status\":{\"code\":0,\"text\":\"Patient is eligible to claim for Medicare with details provided.\"}},\"healthFundStatus\":{\"status\":{\"code\":0,\"text\":\"Patient is known to the Health Fund specified in the request.\"}},\"medicareAssessment\":{\"currentPatient\":{\"currentMembership\":{\"memberNumber\":\"2953930273\",\"memberRefNumber\":\"1\"},\"currentMember\":{\"familyName\":\"FLINTSTONE\",\"givenName\":\"FRED\"}},\"medicalEvent\":[{\"service\":[{\"id\":\"0001\",\"benefit\":\"0\",\"chargeAmount\":\"15232\",\"dateOfService\":\"2024-06-02\",\"explanationCode\":\"162\",\"itemNumber\":\"00058\",\"scheduleFee\":\"0\"}],\"id\":\"01\",\"cardFlagCode\":\" \"}],\"claimId\":\"64775\",\"fundLocationId\":\"HSL99995\",\"lodgementDate\":\"2024-07-25\"}},\"transactionId\":\"HSL99995NsAaVN7LsHtrzujM\",\"status\":\"SUCCESS\"}]}",
            "ResponseContentType": "application/json"
        },
        {
            "AckDate": "2024-07-25T10:46:42.233",
            "Name": "Initial Claim Request",
            "Request": "{\"claim\":{\"patient\":{\"medicare\":{\"memberNumber\":\"2111111111\",\"memberRefNumber\":\"1\"},\"healthFund\":{\"memberNumber\":\"222222\",\"memberRefNumber\":\"1\",\"organisation\":\"HAM\"},\"identity\":{\"dateOfBirth\":\"1997-09-22\",\"familyName\":\"FLINTSTONE\",\"givenName\":\"FRED\",\"sex\":\"2\"}},\"medicalEvent\":[{\"service\":[{\"dateOfService\":\"2024-06-02\",\"id\":\"0001\",\"chargeAmount\":\"15232\",\"itemNumber\":\"00058\",\"numberOfPatientsSeen\":\"1\"}],\"serviceProvider\":{\"providerNumber\":\"2441301F\"},\"id\":\"01\",\"ifcIssueCode\":\"X\"}],\"principalProvider\":{\"providerNumber\":\"2441301F\"},\"accident\":{\"accidentInd\":\"N\"},\"accountPaidInd\":\"N\",\"accountReferenceId\":\"kj32\",\"claimTypeCode\":\"AG\",\"compensationClaimInd\":\"N\",\"facilityId\":\"0031620B\",\"serviceTypeCode\":\"O\"}}",
            "RequestContentType": "application/json",
            "Response": "{\"status\":\"SUCCESS\"}",
            "ResponseContentType": "application/json"
        }
    ]
}

Example Delphi 2007 code:
    unit Unit1;
    
    interface
    
    uses
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
      uLkJSON,
    
      Dialogs, StdCtrls;
    
    type
      TForm1 = class(TForm)
        Button1: TButton;
        procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
        procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
        procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
            NameStringList:TStringList;
            RequestStringList:TStringList;
            RequestContentTypeStringList:TStringList;
            ResponseStringList:TStringList;
            ResponseContentTypeStringList:TStringList;
      end;
    
    var
      Form1: TForm1;
    
    implementation
    
    {$R *.dfm}
    function LoadTextFile: string;
    var
      OpenDialog: TOpenDialog;
      StringList: TStringList;
    begin
      Result := '';
      OpenDialog := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);
      try
        OpenDialog.Filter := 'Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*';
        if OpenDialog.Execute then
        begin
          StringList := TStringList.Create;
          try
            StringList.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog.FileName);
            Result := StringList.Text;
          finally
            StringList.Free;
          end;
        end;
      finally
        OpenDialog.Free;
      end;
    end;
    
    {$IFDEF DEBUG}
    procedure DebugAppendLog(newtext:string);
    var LogFileName: String;    {Name of file to log to.}
    var fhLogFile : TextFile;  {File handle - log file.}
    begin
        //exit; {do nothing, exit i.e. turn off this debugging.}
        LogFileName:='d:\Notifications.txt';
        AssignFile(fhLogFile, LogFileName);
            if (FileExists(LogFileName)) then begin
                Append(fhLogFile);
            end else begin
                Rewrite(fhLogFile);
            end;   {if}
        Writeln(fhLogFile, newtext);
        System.CloseFile(fhLogFile);
    end;
    {$ENDIF}
    
    
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      FileContents: string;
      var jsonbase, DataArray, DataObject: TlkJSONbase;    //as per 3rd party unit uLkJSON
      var I:Integer;
    begin
        FileContents := LoadTextFile;
        // Parse the JSON string
        jsonbase := TlkJSON.ParseText(FileContents);
    
        if Assigned(jsonbase) then
        begin
            try
            // Access the "Data" array
            DataArray := jsonbase.Field['Data'];
            if Assigned(DataArray) and (DataArray.Count > 0) then
            begin
                for I := 0 to Pred(DataArray.Count) do
                begin
                    // Access the object and object values in the "Data" array
                    DataObject := DataArray.Child[I];
                    NameStringList.add(DataObject.Field['Name'].Value);
                    RequestStringList.add(DataObject.Field['Request'].Value);
                    RequestContentTypeStringList.add(DataObject.Field['RequestContentType'].Value);
                    ResponseStringList.add(DataObject.Field['Response'].Value);
                    ResponseContentTypeStringList.add(DataObject.Field['ResponseContentType'].Value);
        {$IFDEF DEBUG}
            DebugAppendLog(PChar(
                            'Debug ' + FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss', Now)
                            + ' NameStringList:' + ' [I] [' +  IntToStr(I) + '] ' + NameStringList[I]
                            + ' RequestStringList:' + ' [I] [' +  IntToStr(I) + '] ' + RequestStringList[I]
                            + ' RequestContentTypeStringList:' + ' [I] [' +  IntToStr(I) + '] ' + RequestContentTypeStringList[I]
                            + ' ResponseStringList:' + ' [I] [' +  IntToStr(I) + '] ' + ResponseStringList[I]
                            + ' ResponseContentTypeStringList:' + ' [I] [' +  IntToStr(I) + '] ' + ResponseContentTypeStringList[I]
                              )) ;
            //OutputDebugString(PChar(
            //                'Debug NameStringList:'
            //                + ' [I] [' +  IntToStr(I) + '] ' + NameStringList[I]
            //                  )) ;
        {$ENDIF}
                end;
            end;
            finally
                jsonbase.Free;
            end;
    
        end;
    end;
    
    
    
    
    procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
        NameStringList:=TStringList.create;
        RequestStringList:=TStringList.create;
        RequestContentTypeStringList:=TStringList.create;
        ResponseStringList:=TStringList.create;
        ResponseContentTypeStringList:=TStringList.create;
    end;
    
    procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    begin
          //Free the 5 stringlist objects
        NameStringList.free;
        RequestStringList.free;
        RequestContentTypeStringList.free;
        ResponseStringList.free;
        ResponseContentTypeStringList.free;
    end;
    
    end.


uLKJSON added the TlkJsonDateTime class in 1.08, but it seems the date/time handling is broken. So yes, stick with 1.07, or use a different library
